# SSH into a Remote Machine with a Password

Tags: ssh, password

I'm to trying to `dd` a remote disk using SSH with the following command:

```sh
ssh userfoo@111.111.111 "dd if=/dev/xvda1 | gzip -1 -"  |  dd of=/home/user/image.gz
```

I get the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host 111.111.111 port 22: Connection timed out
```

I'm guessing it's because userfoo needs to enter a password in order to SSH into 111.111.111. If so, how would I edit my command in order to specify a password?

Comment: Read any SSH tutorial, it will explain you how to set up things to avoid typing a password. BTW, an IPv4 address is like `123.123.234.101` (i.e. four numbers between 0 & 255). You could try  `ssh -v` to understand what is happenning

Comment: As described in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html , you need to copy your pem key to a file on the local system and pass the filename to ssh with the `-i` option.  It's odd that putty works but ssh can't even connect. Do you need to specify a port other than 22 in putty?

Answer (score 4):

Running this command without SSH keys should prompt you for a password.
I am using something similar and don't have any problems.

Most probably you are having problems connecting to the ssh server. Make sure

1. You have access to the server. You can run `traceroute your.server.ip.address` to see if you can connect to it.
2. Make sure you have the ssh server up and running on port 22 - it might run on different port, or down. Try `ssh -v userfoo@192.168.1.1` to see if you can even connect.
3. `userfoo` might not have permissions to connect trough ssh, if you have another user, you can test with it.

***Edit***

It appears in one of the comments you are using PuTTY - which usually is not a problem but it reveals that you are trying to execute this from a Windows machine.
Unfortunately this command will not work as you are piping to your PC, and that means the client need to have `dd` installed.
This part - `dd of=/home/user/image.gz` is actually executed on your PC, not on the server.

That would be your problem if you manage to connect to the server. 
You should be able to log in trough ssh to the server, and it seems that is not the situation.

I have tested the IP you posted here ending with `11.26` and there is no response on port 22 from the SSH server. You need first to fix that.

Comment: 1. I get * * * on every number except 1, I assume that means I can connect? 2. Yes, it's on port 22. Using "ssh -v userfoo@111.111.1.1" gives me a time out error, too. 3. userfoo does have permission to SSH (I can SSH with that username using PuTTY).

Comment: `PuTTY` thats ya problem :) I am editing my answer now with more details.
If you get time out error when only trying to connect there is a problem with ssh. You should be able to connect in order to execute that command. And time out means that the client(your PC) waited too long without response from the server.

Comment: Do you think that because that IP address points to an Amazon EC2 Instance running Linux it doesn't let me SSH from the command line? AWS requires a PEM key to connect, which I have specified from PuTTY when logging in using that client. However, once I'm in the command line, that's when I can't :~$ ssh userfoo@111.111.111. Is there any way I can connect to that IP using PuTTY then download the dd image to my Windows machine?